# Basic Javascript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to learn javascript Regex and I've hit a problem.

I'm trying to validate with the following rules.

Allow only:

```
Numbers 0-9 
( 
) 
+
-
(space)
```

I have come up with the regex below to handle this:

```
/[0-9\)\(\+\- ]+/i
```

The following matches but shouldn't do because it contains a @ symbol:

```
+0@122 0012
```

I'm using the below to test: (Returns true)

```
/[0-9\)\(\+\- ]+/i.test("+0@122 0012")
```

Thanks.

Comment: There's no constraints, it matches anything with a matcing character, add `^` and `$`.

Comment: +1 because the clarity of your regex question is rare here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your regular expression won't match the "@" character, but it doesn't have to in order for the `.test()` call to return `true`. There just has to be a match somewhere in the string.

If you want to insist that the entire string matches, you have to use `^` and `$` anchors.

```
/^[0-9)(+ -]+$/i.test("+0@122 0012")
```

Comment: D'oh! You beat me by about three seconds!